# Windows Ctrl + V equivalent for Linux terminal

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, copy-paste, clipboard

In windows I can paste the clipboard content using the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

However if I try to achieve the same in Linux terminal using the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> key combination, I get the output:

```
^V
```

How to paste clipboard content to terminal in Linux using keybord?

Comment: What's your terminal client? Are you on Linux and then running a terminal?  On Windows and then accessing via Putty or similar?  The answer will vary depending on the terminal client you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Insert</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Insert</kbd> paste. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste) this is in accordance with the IBM Common User Access (CUA) standard. It works in all the X11 terminals that I have tried it on (but it seems xterm for some reason adds `5~` while copying) and it also works in putty from Windows. I like it because I can use only my right hand (using right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the keyboard combination:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: What the heck is that supposed to do?

Comment: Quite simple, paste the clipboard content

Comment: Which terminal client are you using that supports that shortcut?

Comment: bash shell, and the terminology is wrong, it is which shell

Comment: Sorry but that's where you're wrong.  Ctrl-Shift-V on any terminal client that doesn't have such a shortcut acts as a plain Ctrl-V which allows you to enter a control key in the shell.

Comment: Which terminal client are you using?

Comment: @JuliePelletier rancho may be using gnome-terminal, it supports Ctrl-Shift-V (and Ctrl-Shift-C).